# Analyzing WAV file faster than playback speed

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I need to implement a spectrogram of WAV files for a tool we're building. It needs to display the spectrogram for the entire file in one go (think Audacity).

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/circuitBurn/69x7ycb3/3/) of my starting point. This function only logs in 'playback time'. Is it possible to get the frequency data any other way?

```
var freqData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
scp.onaudioprocess = function()
{
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqData);
    console.log(freqData);
};
```

Comment: looks like the log is slowing you down. i can analyze a 5min mp3  file in about 5secs

Comment: At the very least, use a service worker to do your FFT analysis, so you don't block the actual on-page JS?

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`OfflineAudioContext`](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#OfflineAudioContext) as the destination instead of an `AudioContext`.  You probably also want to check that the buffer size for the `ScriptProcessorNode` makes sense for the FFT size of the AnalyserNode.

I'm not sure every browser allows the `ScriptProcessorNode` to work nicely with an `OfflineAudioContext`.